# Asp .NET Core SignalR Display server time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I never used Signalr and can't find an example how to show server time and keep it updated using signalr on client

this is the hub

```
public class ClockHub : Hub
{
    public async Task DisplayTime()
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("DisplayTime", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
    }
}
```

on client side i have this

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/clock").build();
```

how can i get the time sent from server to client and keep it updated?

**UPDATE**

here is the code that is working

```
 setInterval(function () {

        var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/clock").build();

        connection.start().then(function () {

            connection.invoke("DisplayTime", ).catch(function (err) {
                return console.error(err.toString());
            });

        }).catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });

        connection.on("DisplayTime", function (time) {
            $('#server-date').html(time);
        });

        },1000);
```

Comment: You need to invoke `DisplayTime` on the connection and then manage the received message. Many SignalR tutorials show you how to do this. Start with `connection.invoke('DisplayTime');` and then `connection.on('DisplayTime', functon(data){//stuff});`. You can see why it's a good idea to have different send/receive names.

Comment: sorry what is this message variable? I don't want to send anything, just get the time from server and display

Comment: if use invoke first i get this error `Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.`

Comment: I'd also use `Clients.Caller.SendAsync` , except if you want to update all clients as soon as one of them requests server time.

Comment: _"and keep it updated"_ How often do you want to update? Every second? Every Minute? Depending on the client count that could put quite some strain on the server.

Comment: enough to keep the time synced with server i suppose

Comment: @Fildor I have updated my post with a working example, although i'm not sure if this is correct

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid duplicates caused by multiple intervals, this code should work:

Hubs/ClockHub.cs:

```
public class ClockHub : Hub
{
    public async Task PrintTime()
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("DisplayTime", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

wwwroot/js/clock.js:

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/clockHub").build();

connection.on("DisplayTime", function (time) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = time;
    document.getElementById("serverDate").appendChild(li);
});

connection.start().then(function () {

}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

setInterval(function () {

    connection.invoke("PrintTime").catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });

}, 1000);
```

Pages/Index.cshtml:

```
@page
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <ul id="serverDate"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/clock.js"></script>
```

The rest of the code can be found in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr).